# Find an element in cypress to click that can't be found

Tags: frontend, cypress, e2e-testing

I have been trying for hours to get an element and click on it but cypress is not being very nice. Here is the front end code

[image]

I have tried all of these

```
cy.get('#Area\ Data').click()
cy.get('#Area\ Data path').click()
cy.get('#Area\ Data > .circle_icon__1sTPA > svg').click()
cy.get('#Area\ Data > .circle_icon__1sTPA').click()
cy.get('.circle_left_9KD8d > .circle_container__2H4VS > #Area\ Data > .circle_icon__1sTPA > svg').click()
```

any idea why none of these are working?

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
cy.get('[id="Area Data"]').click()
```

OR

```
cy.get('[data-id="Area Data"]').click()
```

In case the click is not happening you can add `{force: true}`. Forcing a click overrides the actionable checks Cypress applies and will automatically fire the events.

```
cy.get('[id="Area Data"]').click({force: true})
```